# C# htmlagilitypack node.xpath

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm making a webscraper application in C# with the htmlagilitypack, now i want to have a dropdown to select an element in the document. I want to see the string of the xpath to it the result i was hoping for

> //a[@href='http://www.google.com']

but the xpath i got was

> /html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/a[1]

is there any way to get a more readable xpath back?
the code i'm using is:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(data);
List<string> nodes = new List<string>();
foreach (HtmlNode n in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()){
        nodes.Add(n.XPath);
}
List<string> ComboItems = nodes.Distinct().ToList();
_comboFilterNode.ItemsSource = ComboItems;
```

it doesnt have to be the format of the first example i gave but i do need something so you dont need to read the whole HTML file to know what element it is.

or a way to get:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/"/>
```

it isnt always a `<a>` and i dont want the innerHTML

Thanks for the help in advance :D

Comment: *"...and i dont want the innerHTML"*, what's the problem with `innerHTML`? (I would go this way instead of trying to get distinct XPath of a given element which would be much more complex to build)

Comment: if i get the innerHTML i get all the child elements too, and i dont want that

Answer (score 0):

You can build HTML markup of a given `HtmlNode` excluding its content by using combination of `HtmlNode` name and the attributes collection.

For example, assuming that you have `HtmlNode` instance referenced by variable `foo`, you can do as follow :

```
HtmlNode foo;

var attributes = string.Join(" ", 
                             foo.Attributes
                                .Select(o => String.Format("{0}=\"{1}\"", o.Name, o.Value))
                            );

//combine element name and the attributes collection to create a representative HTML markup
var result = String.Format("<{0} {1}/>", foo.Name, attributes);
```

**Full working demo example :**

```
var html = @"<a href='http://www.google.com/'>
    <span>foobar</span>
    <span>foobaz</span>
</a>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var foo = doc.DocumentNode.FirstChild;
var attributes = string.Join(" ", 
                         foo.Attributes
                            .Select(o => String.Format("{0}=\"{1}\"", o.Name, o.Value))
                        );
var result = String.Format("<{0} {1}/>", foo.Name, attributes);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vvJJHU)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I now have:

```
foreach (HtmlNode n in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants())
{
        if (n.Attributes.Count != 0)
        {
              nodes.Add("//"+n.Name + "[@" + n.Attributes[0].Name+"='"+n.Attributes[0].Value+"']");
         }
         else
         {
               nodes.Add(n.Name);
          }
  }

  List<string> ComboItems = nodes.Distinct().ToList();
  _comboFilterNode.ItemsSource = ComboItems;
```

Sadly i now only have one attribute to filter it on, but it works for what it needs to do and it gives back in XPath.